# Manter os zeros depois do ponto

Tags: javascript, array

Bom dia a todos. 
Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var somaR = 0;
    var somaN = 0;
    var project = [
       {part: 'Renault', partNumber: 1234, project: 'X19', gap: 15.000}, 
       {part: 'Renault', partNumber: 1234, project: 'X19', gap: 600}, 

    ]

    function groupBy(array, f) {
        var groups = {};
        array.forEach(function(o) {
            var group = JSON.stringify(f(o));
            groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
            groups[group].push(o);
        });
        return Object.keys(groups).map(function(group) {
            return groups[group];
        });
    }

    var projectIguais = groupBy(project, function(item) {
        return [item.part, item.partNumber, item.project];
    }).map(function(data){
        return {
            totalGap: data.reduce(function(total, valor){return total + valor.gap;}, 0),
            itens: data
        };
    });

    console.log(projectIguais);


    for (var i in projectIguais) {

        var partNumberItem = "Part Number: " +projectIguais[i].itens[0].partNumber;
        var projectItem = "Project: " +projectIguais[i].itens[0].project;
        var gap = "Gap: "+projectIguais[i].itens[0].gap;
        var totalGapItem = projectIguais[i].totalGap;

        console.log(partNumberItem);
        console.log(projectItem);
        console.log(gap);

        if(projectIguais[i].itens[0].part == 'Renault'){
            somaR += totalGapItem;
        }
        if(projectIguais[i].itens[0].part == 'Nissan'){
            somaN += totalGapItem;
        }
    }

    console.log("Soma Renault", somaR);
    console.log("Soma Nissan", somaN);
```

Dentro do array project tenho o gap 15.000 mas na hora de fazer o cálculo, o valor do gap fica 15.

Exp: O código pega dentro do array o mesmo partNumber e projeto, soma o gap e me devolve o total do gap por projeto. 
No meu array tenho um gap 15.000 e outro gap 600 mas no cálculo está me retornando gap 615 porque está removendo os zeros depois do ponto.

Como faço para manter o 15.000 no cálculo?

Comment: O Json está errado, o correto de um json para numérico na casa de milhares é receber sem nenhum ponto, exp: `15000`, o `.` separa a fração, exp: `15000.58 => 15.000,58`

Answer (score 1):

## Resposta rápida

Escreva:

```
{part: 'Renault', partNumber: 1234, project: 'X19', gap: 15000},
```

No lugar de:

```
{part: 'Renault', partNumber: 1234, project: 'X19', gap: 15.000},
```

E na hora de mostrar o valor, ai sim você coloca os pontos e virgulas para separar milhar e decimal:

```
// .toLocaleString('pt-BR') vai aplicar o formato brasileiro no Number
// ou seja, um ponto var separar o milhar e uma vírgula vai separar o decimal
var gap = "Gap: " + (projectIguais[i].itens[0].gap).toLocaleString('pt-BR');

// Use em todas as saídas que quiser formatar
console.log("Soma Nissan", (somaN).toLocaleString('pt-BR'));
```

## Explicação disso tudo

O ponto ".", na notação americana (que o javascript usa) é entendido como a nossa virgula aqui no Brasil, ou seja, ele separa o número inteiro das casas decimais, portanto escrever R$ 15.000 é igual a escrever R$ 15,000 (nós lemos isso como "quinze reais", sempre ignoramos as casas decimais quando estão ZERADAS).

### Conclusão

Para trabalhar com os números no javascript não use nenhuma pontuação para separar os milhares e use o ponto (e não a virgula) para separar as casas decimais, simples assim.

### Bônus

Crie uma função para facilitar a formatação (e a sua vida):

```
function ptbr(n) {
    // parse só pra garantir
    return Number(n).toLocaleString('pt-BR')
}
```

Dai você usa assim:

```
var gap = "Gap: " + ptbr(projectIguais[i].itens[0].gap);
```